# Xcode5 ( 3.5" screen to 4 inch )

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator, autolayout

Recently I had upgraded to Xcode 5 and opened a project that had been created in Xcode 4.6.1. All the images and buttons had moved around so I went back and re-arranged everything. Now a new problem has occurred, when I switch from the 4" simulator to 3.5 inch images get cut off, buttons and toolbars move around as well. I been searching for an answer for days and Im new to stackoverflow so I hope I have follow all rules and my question in the correct section.

Few notes on the project:

Using Autolayout, Size - Inferred, Orientation - Inferred

Opens in: Default 5.0, Project Deployment Target 7.0, View as: iOS 7.0 and Later

Comment: Do all of your objects have proper constraints using Autolayout?

Comment: Cant find constraints they don't show.

Comment: Click on an object and under the utilities pane go to the size attributes. If you scroll down there you will see all of the constraints that are on that object. If you do not have any constraints then that is the reason you are having this problem.

Comment: No constraints show, only the following message: The selected views have no constraints. At build time explicit left, top, width, and height constraints will be generated for the view.

Comment: I will add an answer with what you need to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you do not have any constraints on your objects. You will need to add them in order for autolayout to work the way you want.

If you are not wanting to add constraints programmatically than you can simply add them to objects in IB.

Click the object you want to add constraints to:

Editor -> Resolve Autolayout Issues -> Add Missing Constraints.

That will give you a good place to start with and you can further adjust the constraints from there.

Comment: Getting the following warning message, "Frame for "Image view - Name" will be different at run time.

Comment: Open the document outline in IB. Then there should be a warning icon there. You can click on it and fix those errors manually, one by one.

Comment: Thank you so much, your a life saver! I have been searching for days for an answer. I unfortunately don't see a solution for warning message. I checked the interface builder.

Comment: You're welcome! Be sure to select the answer if it is what you needed. As for what you're looking for, open the document outline in IB. You will see a breakdown of all the objects for each scene. At the top there will be a yellow arrow. You can click that to view the constraint problems on that scene. On that pane it might say something like, 'Misplaced Views'. You can then click the yellow warning triangle to choose a solution. I would suggest the 'Update Constraints' option.